# R: Import CSV but having problems with special characters

Tags: r, csv, import

I'm trying to import a big file containing several price series in a sequence of 3 columns, but the number of columns is completely variable:

```
Date %change Price    Date2 %change2 Price2    Date3 %change3 Price3
```

The splitting of this imported CSV into separate xts is done later on in a loop. My problem is that 1000 is saved in this CSV as 1'000 (in the prices columns), all values start initially lower though. So R assumes that the Price columns are num and the import crashes when reaching the first 1'000 values.

How can I handle this in the import statement. I tried to change all columns to character, but no success:

```
read.table(paste(Path,FileName,sep=""),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=";", colClasses=c("character"))
```

Comment: Try setting `quote=""` to disable quoting. I suspect that the `'` is being interpreted as a quote.

Comment: basically works thanks. However now it imports way too much. My file only containts 5700 rows but now it imports the maximum of 49999 observations with NAs in the last 43000 rows..any way to avoid that?

Comment: Do you have the correct number of columns?

Comment: unfortuntately not. very variable and changes every day.

Comment: Then you will need to roll your own import using `readLines` or `scan`. `read.table` is designed for rectangular (table) data.

Comment: You can try to set all columns to 'character'  using colClasses='character' with read.table().